# Usar diferentes simbolos por pontos

Tags: jquery, flot

Estou utilizando o plugin [float charts](http://www.flotcharts.org/) para gerar gráficos com linha.
Até então tenho este gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como configuração do `plugin`, estou informando que esta linha deve ter uma `symbol` do tipo `circle`

Mas eu preciso que o simbolo do meio, não seja um círculo, seja um outro simbolo de acordo com uma determinada condição

Como posso fazer isso? Há algum plugin extra ou até mesmo um outro plugin para charts que me deixe fazer isso ?

**[Edit]**

Conforme solicitado.

O gráfico em si é gerado dos dados que são passados a ele.
Atualmente estou passando da seguinte forma:

```
  var data = [
            {
                data: [
                    [1, 100], 
                    [2, 150], 
                    [3, 200], 
                    [4, 205], 
                    [5, 100], 
                    [6, 100], 
                    [7, 100], 
                    [8, 200], 
                    [9, 100], 
                    [10, 100] 
                ],
                color: '#21610B',
                points: { symbol: "circle" }
            },

            ];
```

Conforme eu citei, o valor de `symbol` é `circle`, ou seja, todo ponto será um círculo, mas eu desejo que alguns determinados pontos, conforme uma determinada condição, este ponto não seja `circle`

Também possui as options, que estão dessa forma:

```
 var options = {
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: true
                },
                points: {
                    show: true,
                    radius: 3
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Post o código que tem feito, ou se possível coloque como fiddle.

Comment: @Marconi eu postei o código que está

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rod.

Sim é possível.

```
$.plot('#placeholder', [{
    data: [
        [1, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 4],
        [5, 9]
    ],
    lines: {
        show: true
    },
    points: {
        show: true,
        symbol: function(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow) {

            if (x == 0) {
                 var size = radius * Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI / Math.sin(Math.PI / 3));
                var height = size * Math.sin(Math.PI / 3);
                ctx.moveTo(x - size/2, y + height/2);
                ctx.lineTo(x + size/2, y + height/2);
                if (!shadow) {
                    ctx.lineTo(x, y - height/2);
                    ctx.lineTo(x - size/2, y + height/2);
                }
            }
            else {
                var size = radius * Math.sqrt(Math.PI) / 2;
                ctx.rect(x - size, y - size, size + size, size + size);
            }

        }
    },
    color: '#CB4B4B',
    label: 'My Data'
}]);
```

Porém você vai ter que utilizar a lógica de criação dos símbolos. Eu tirei a lógica aqui https://code.google.com/p/flot/source/browse/trunk/jquery.flot.symbol.js?r=263 isso também permite você criar qualquer símbolo.

Conforme a documentação do flot, o parâmetro symbol pode receber uma função de callback. Documentação aqui https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#plot-options de um **CTRL + F symbol** e você vai achar isso **symbol: "circle" or function**

Veja esse exemplo funcionando aqui http://jsfiddle.net/yx659y9f/

Para converter os pontos de coordenadas para os pontos do dataset

```
console.log(this.allocatedAxes[0].c2p(x));

console.log(this.allocatedAxes[1].c2p(y));
```

Exemplo no jsfiddle onde mudo o ponto quando o X é = a 2 http://jsfiddle.net/9hz947s9/

Comment: Cara, é bem isso mesmo...problema não é nem desenhar o ponto, é reconhecer os pontos, eu coloquei console.log(x) console.log(y) vem uns valores muito loucos, difícil de reconhecer qual é o ponto em questão hauauah alguma dica?

Comment: Existe um método interno do próprio flot que converte ponto de coordenada no ponto do seu dataset.

Veja minha edição

Comment: Perfeito :DD obrigado Erick

Comment: Erick, você sabe me dizer se há como usar imagem (png,jpge..etc) em vez de canvas? rs

Comment: @Rod como assim? Você quer desenhar o gráfico em uma imagem? É isso? Se for então não, nunca tentei fazer isso porém pelo que eu já li de todo código fonte do Flot não creio que seja possível. Se for uma SVG talvez de.

Comment: Não, ao invés de usar "circle", "square", eu poder passar um png..algo assim

Comment: Consegue sim. Ainda utilizando o canvas, porque é como o plugin renderiza seus elementos. Porém da para exibir sim uma imagem do lugar de desenhar um circulo ou quadrado. Dê uma lida aqui http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp